# How can I copy a java.lang.reflect.Method?

Tags: java, reflection

I have an API that takes in a `Method` and stores it to call later.  In order to invoke it I have to do `setAccessible(true)`.  Before I do that, I'd like to make a defensive copy.  But how?

I thought of

```
method.getDeclaringClass()
      .getDeclaredMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
```

but that won't necessarily give me the same method back in the presence of bridge methods (or other cases where two methods have the same name/parameter types but different return types).

I could loop over `method.getDeclaringClass().getDeclaredMethod()` and look for an exact match, but that seems inefficient.

---

An example that illustrates why a defensive copy might be nice:

```
Method method = ...;

// Does setAccessible(true)
MyInvoker invoker = new MyInvoker(method);

// Sometime later, the user uses the same Method rather than re-retrieving it
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(...);
method.setAccessible(false);
// Oops, now MyInvoker is broken
```

---

An example where `getDeclaredMethod()` returns a different method:

```
interface Iface {
    Object get();
}

class Impl implements Iface {
    @Override
    public String get() {
        return "foo";
    }
}

for (Method method : Impl.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    System.out.println(method);
    System.out.println(copy(method));
    System.out.println();
}

private Method copy(Method method) {
    try {
        return method.getDeclaringClass()
                .getDeclaredMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

For me, this prints:

> ```
> public java.lang.String com.maluuba.api.Impl.get()
> public java.lang.String com.maluuba.api.Impl.get()
>
> public java.lang.Object com.maluuba.api.Impl.get()
> public java.lang.String com.maluuba.api.Impl.get()
> ```

Comment: Why do you want to make a defensive copy?

Comment: Under what conditions would the method change in ways you want to avoid?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Because mutating constructor arguments is generally a surprising thing to do.  And to avoid situations where the client later calls `setAccessible(false)`.

Comment: @TavianBarnes Can you give an example of a class where bridge methods mess up your current solution? As far as two methods with the same name and parameter types, but different return types: That cannot happen. They would be considered duplicate methods.

Comment: @Jeffrey I added one.  A more dangerous example is something like ProGuard, which can rename two completely different methods to have the same name but different return types.

Comment: This API is yours? This looks so messy, why don't you use something like a Command Design Pattern ? (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/command_pattern.htm). Using reflection in java should be your last option. Instead of keeping Methods, just store objects implementing an interface, there's no need for reflection this way.

Comment: What quantity of methods are you likely to *actually* deal with in this way?

Comment: @Bohemian Perhaps ~100 at startup, and ~5 per request

Comment: But overall, during the life of the server, how many *different* methods will be invoked? The reason I ask, is if it's only a few thousand, you can cache the method found for a given method request, say in a `ConcurrentHashMap`.. It would be your current speed on the first access, but then would be lightening fast thereafter. You could actively warm the cache up on start up by collecting stats on the methods actually used and prime your cache to avoid the cost of the first lookup during transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do what you originally suggested and rely on the contract of [`Method#equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) which states

> Compares this `Method` against the specified object. Returns `true` if
> the objects are the same. Two `Method`s are the same if they were
> declared by the same class and have the same name and formal parameter
> types and return type.

So you won't be able to use the `getDeclaredMethod(String, Object...)` method. You'll have to do an array lookup on the `Method[]` returned by `getDeclaredMethods()`. For example,

```
private Method copy(Method method) {
    Class<?> clazz = method.getDeclaringClass();
    for (Method declaredMethod : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        if (declaredMethod.equals(method)) {
            return declaredMethod; // return the new one
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("This should not happen.");
}
```